# Getting a blank white screen with no errors in console

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app, built in vuejs, compiles with yarn build and yarn cordova-build-ios respectively.

It works if I do platform add browser. and cordova-serve-browser.

But, in IOS, or even OSX it doesnt. I tried to use the yarn build and put in phonegap build, and same issue.

Using a docs, I enabled xcode debug and safari debug for the app. Neither in xcode or the safari app are there any errors in network or console tabs.

## edit

After some reading, I testing the following, the alert after new Vue() never fires

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Toastr from 'vue-toastr'

Vue.use(router)
Vue.use(Toastr)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

alert(navigator.userAgent);
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
} else {
    onDeviceReady(); //this is the browser
}
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert('**');
  const vue = new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
  alert(vue.toSource())
}
```

Comment: I'll add that yarn cordova-serve-browser works

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rebuilding the front end part, it seems it was related to paths...

Also, for IOS it would not work from the root, but had to go into src folder and run cordova run ios (rather than yarn cordova-serve-ios from the root)

But it works